Turning off Rotate suggestion in stock android
Whenever auto-rotate is "off", the lower-right corner of the screen will have this button that allows for manual rotation when you press on it. I know that this is a built-in feature in Android systems, but I wanted to see if there an explicit way to turn off this feature as the button can be sometime very annoying.
For example, as many have shown in older posts, Samsung's Android settings even has an option that permits you to turn off this feature. Sadly, my Nothing Phone 2 does not have this option and it supposedly uses stock Android. Current version is 14
How to remove the manual rotate icon?

So in the end, I tried different methods. But taking inspiration from some other posts, the final solution that worked for me was to run a adb commad to turn the feature off. The command itself is this one below (change adb to .\adb.exe if you are using windows 11's command prompt as terminal):
adb shell settings put secure show_rotation_suggestions 0

"0" is to turn this feature off, and "1" is to turn this feature back on.
The detailed steps to reach this process is the following should anyone face a same problem.

Turn on the developer mode in your device
Turn on USB-debugging
Download the android spk plateform tools from this link: https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools
Unzip this folder and depending on your OS, use the terminal to reach the unzipped folder and then run adb devices. This will show you if your device is connected
(in my case, since I was using Windows11, and the command prompt as terminal, I had to run .\adb.exe instead of simply adb; so for me it was .\adb.exe devices)
Once you have confirmed that your device is indeed connected; you can just run the command to turn off the rotate suggestion feature: adb shell settings put secure show_rotation_suggestions 0

Conclusion:
I think they should add a button inside the rotate setting page; that would allow users to have the ability to turn this feature on or off; The button whilst provided more control is sometime prone to mistouch especially if you have a big finger and you are using your phone already in landscape mode.

Strange: I don't have a manual rotate button whether or not I have the automatic rotate button active or not (Android 13 on a Sony Xperia 10 III).
I use a Rotation Control App to set App-specific rotation orientation automatically or manually (from the settings bar).
Maybe that could help you?

So I think it depends on the version. But specifically, I have a nothing phone 2 which supposedly use stock android 14. Therefore whenever the auto-rotate is set as "ON" it will show a rotate suggestion at the corner of the screen to potentially have the user have the ability to turn the screen rotation manually.
